# How to pivot vertical rows into column data using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to pivot vertical rows record of SQL Server table into column data. I have tried few queries but not able to achieve the result.

I have a table called `TRANSACTIONLOG` which has three columns

```
CREATEDATE, TRANSACTION, COUNTS
```

[image: Table record]

I need to GROUP the record on `CREATEDATE` and show transaction types as a column and COUNTS as its value.

Below is what the result should look like -

[image: Output Result]

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with some conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT CREATEDATE
    , [INSERT] = MAX(case when [TRANSACTION] = 'INSERT' then COUNTS end)
    , [UPDATE] = MAX(case when [TRANSACTION] = 'UPDATE' then COUNTS end)
    , [DELETE] = MAX(case when [TRANSACTION] = 'DELETE' then COUNTS end)
FROM TRANSACTIONLOG
GROUP BY CREATEDATE
ORDER BY CREATEDATE
```

Comment: Above query will not print the COUNTS value.

Comment: This will work - SELECT CREATEDATE
    , [INSERT] = MAX(case when [TRANSACTION] = 'INSERT' then COUNTS end)
    , [UPDATE] =MAX(case when [TRANSACTION] = 'UPDATE' then COUNTS end)
    , [DELETE] = MAX(case when [TRANSACTION] = 'DELETE' then COUNTS end)
FROM TRANSACTIONLOG
GROUP BY CREATEDATE
ORDER BY CREATEDATE

Comment: @Sks I was assuming you needed to count the rows (the column name confused me). I will adjust my answer. ;)